# How to merge two texts given the common base version of both texts?

Tags: python, merge, diff, text-processing, google-diff-match-patch

Similar to how git merge two branches but:

- using python
- instead of two branches we have `text1` and `text2`
- instead of common commit we have `text0` - previous version of both text1 and text2

[diff-match-patch](https://github.com/google/diff-match-patch) probably can be used to accomplish this task, but I didn't find appropriate method neither in doc nor in python package source code (because docs are not complete).

So far I come up with this:

```
c = "some base text with meaning"
a = "changed base text with meaning"
b = "some base text without meaning"
p1 = dmp.patch_make(c, a)
p2 = dmp.patch_make(c, b)
dmp.patch_apply(p1 + p2, c)
> ('changed base text without meaning', [True, True])
```

It looks like it works, but I'm not sure if this is correct method.
Can someone experienced with diff-match-patch approve this?

Comment: I guess it is correct as long as it does the work. Is the conflict handling (or lack thereof) enough for your needs? What do you expect to happen when `a = 'some base text with foo'` and `b = 'some base text with bar'`?